# How do I get the lockbox in this location (Aberdeen - West part of the docks)?

Tags: sleeping-dogs

How do I get the lockbox in this location? This is in Aberdeen - Southeast of Chiang Mai Sewer Interchange, at the West side of the docks. I tried different points of approach, but am unable to get to its location (it's at a roof, I believe).

Screenshots (click on an image to view the higher-res image):

Map of the lockbox' location
[image]

It is located at the roof of the structure in front of the player character here. I can't get a screenshot with the lockbox in view, but it is shown in the minimap in this screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First, climb up the dumpster by approaching it and pressing the climb key (<kbd>Space</kbd> on the PC). You'll then be able to press that key again to get on to the roof:

   [image: Wei climbing dumpster]
2. Then, go to the right, around the air conditioning unit and follow the roof to the other edge:

   [image: Wei on roof]
3. The lockbox will be to your left, around the corner:

   [image: Wei in front of lockbox]

Comment: D'oh! I tried all sorts of routes except that. (I also thought that the dumpster was unclimbable too.)